# How long does it take to level up your Operation Payback coin in Counterstrike Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How many hours or other criteria does it take to level up or change the color of  your Operation Payback coin in Counterstrike Global Offensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 hours from bronze to silver
50 hours from silver to gold